# Confused about the usage of useReducer assigned to onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reading this blog to understand React's key prop better and one example the author uses is

```js
function Counter() {
  console.log('Counter called')
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(() => {
    console.log('Counter useState initializer')
    return 0
  })
  const increment = () => setCount(c => c + 1)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Counter useEffect callback')
    return () => {
      console.log('Counter useEffect cleanup')
    }
  }, [])
  console.log('Counter returning react elements')
  return <button onClick={increment}>{count}</button>
}
function CounterParent() {
  // using useReducer this way basically ensures that any time you call
  // setCounterKey, the `counterKey` is set to a new object which will
  // make the `key` different resulting in React unmounting the previous
  // component and mounting a new one.
  const [counterKey, setCounterKey] = React.useReducer(c => c + 1, 0)
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setCounterKey}>reset</button>
      <Counter key={counterKey} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I think I understand the part where he uses `reset` button to make the `key` prop different. But the usage of `useReducer` looks foreign to me. First of all `useReducer` should return a `dispatch`, in this case I guess it is `setCounterKey` and then it is passed to `onClick` prop. But I still don't understand why this is even working. Should we call dispatch with an object with the type of action and payload we want?

And I was wondering why he didn't use `useState` instead. And I tried to modify the code to

`const [counterKey, setCounterKey] = React.useState(0);`

but I got this error

> Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the method `movementY` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is a no-op function. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().

Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this error pops out is because you pass the `event` object to `setCounterKey` function on `onClick` event:

```
function CounterParent() {
  const [counterKey, setCounterKey] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      // onClick={setCounterKey} will pass the event object to setCounterKey
     // onClick={(e => setCounterKey(e)} <-- `e` is event object

     // Instead use functional update like so
      <button onClick={() => setCounterKey(p => p + 1)}>reset</button>
      <Counter key={counterKey} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

It's a bad practice, the reason explained in the warning itself, and [in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

On the other hand, using `useReducer`, the `setCounterKey` is already defined with a callback call (`c => c + 1`) so the event not passed.

It is possible to make the exact example with `useState` see an [example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-violet-l32m1?file=/index.js).

[image: Edit Q-62560969-dont pass an event]

> Should we call dispatch with an object with the type of action and payload we want?

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialArg, init);
```

No. Passing an object with `type` is a common Redux pattern. Its really confusing, but the `reducer` function can be anything. Refer to [`useReducer` in docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer).